# Перенос InnoDB таблиц как файлов

Tags: mysql, innodb

Известно, что MySQL таблицы MyISAM хранит в виде трёх файлов: `tbl_name.frm` - описание структуры таблицы, `tbl_name.myd` (myData) - данные, хранящиеся в таблице, `tbl_name.myi` (myIndex) - индексы. Если MySQL сервер остановить, то путём простого копирования этих файлов можно перенести таблицу на другой сервер. Это иногда намного удобнее и быстрее, чем сдампить таблицу на одном сервере и залить дамп на другом.

Вопрос - как проделать этот трюк для таблиц InnoDB? Таблицы там живут в файле (файлах) `ibdata*`, перенести его можно только целиком?

Comment: а разве не надо после копирования файлов с исходного сервера сделать: UNLOCK TABLES; ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Из коробки InnoDB хранит все таблицы в общем пуле ibdata и описанный в вопросе трюк невозможен. Однако, если MySQL сервер настроен на использование [file-per-table tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html), для каждой таблицы будет создаваться отдельная пара файлов (вида `tbl_name.frm` - структура и `tbl_name.ibd` - даныне и индексы). Помимо описанного трюка, это даёт другие преимущества, вроде быстрого выполнения запросов `TRUNCATE TABLE` и возможности получить обратно дисковое пространство, занятое таблицей, при её удалении (в случае использования `ibdata*` дисковое пространство при удалении таблиц не освобождается). Настройка выглядит так (в `my.cnf`):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

При остановленном MySQL сервере файлы `.frm` и `.ibd` можно [копировать и переносить](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-backup.html), как и в случае MyISAM, а если нужно скопировать таким образом таблицу, не останавливая сервер, нужно прибегнуть к хитрости - сбросить на диск кеш и "выгрузить" таблицу (таблицы), которые хотим скопировать:

```
FLUSH TABLES table_one, table_two FOR EXPORT;
```

Теперь файлы `.frm` и `.ibd` можно копировать на лету - разумеется, с момента `FLUSH` до окончания копирования работать с данной таблицей нельзя (но можно с остальными).

"Подключение" перенесённой на другой сервер таблицы InnoDB выглядит так:

1. Создаём на новом месте в базе с таким же именем (это важно), как у базы, в которой находилась переносящаяся таблица, таблицу с такой же структурой, как переносящаяся (пустую)
2. Выполняем

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
   ```
3. Подкладываем скопированные файлы `tbl_name.frm` и `tbl_name.ibd`
4. Выполняем

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tbl_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;
   ```

Вуаля, таблица перенесена!

Перед тем, как впервые воспользоваться этой инструкцией для операций с живыми данными, потренируйтесь на чём-нибудь тестовом, что не жалко испортить. И всегда делайте бекапы!

Answer (score 0):

Крайне не рекомендую так делать, но пришлось реализовать такой такой вариант т.к. была только копия файлов из папки `/var/lib/mysql`

Для начала:

- Копия `/var/lib/mysql` с другого сервера лежит в `/tmp/mysql_old/`
- База которую копируем называется `foo_site`
- В базе куча таблиц, но только `logs` и `sales` являются innoDB таблицами

1. Лоигимися под root, останавливаем mysql и идём в `/var/lib/mysql`

   ```bsh
   sudo su
   service mysql stop
   cd /var/lib/mysql
   ```
2. Бекапим данные innodb которые уже есть

   ```bsh
   tar -czf /tmp/bak_ib.tar.gz ib*
   ```
3. Копиуем данные базы

   ```bsh
   cp /tmp/mysql_old/foo_site ./ -R
   cp /tmp/mysql_old/ibdata1 ./
   chown mysql:mysql foo_site -R
   ```
4. - Открываем настройки mysql

     ```bsh
     nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
     ```
   - И в самый конец добавляем строки

     ```
     [mysqld]
     innodb_file_per_table=1
     ```
5. Запускаем mysql

   ```bsh
   service mysql start
   ```
6. Просим mysql выгрузить данные нужных нам таблиц на диск

   ```sql
   FLUSH TABLES logs, sales FOR EXPORT;
   ```
7. Сохраняем структуру innoDB таблиц

   ```bsh
   mysqldump --no-data -u root --password=<your_pass> foo_site logs sales > /tmp/foo_site_innoDB_tables.sql
   ```
8. Копируем данные готовые для переноса

   ```bsh
   cp foo_site /tmp/foo_site_export -R
   ```
9. Останавливаем mysql и приводим директорию mysql в прежний вид

   ```bsh
   service mysql stop
   rm -rf foo_site
   rm -rf ib*
   tar -xf /tmp/bak_ib.tar.gz
   ```
10. Копируем все данные базы за исключением innoDB таблиц

    ```bsh
    rsync -r --exclude "logs.*" --exclude "sales.*" /tmp/foo_site_export/ ./foo_site
    chown mysql:mysql foo_site -R
    ```
11. В последний раз запускаем mysql и создаём структуру innoDB таблицы

    ```bsh
    service mysql start
    cat /tmp/foo_site_innoDB_tables.sql | mysql foo_site -u root -p
    ```
12. Удаляем .ibd файлы

    ```sql
    ALTER TABLE logs DISCARD TABLESPACE;
    ALTER TABLE sales DISCARD TABLESPACE;
    ```
13. Копируем информацию о таблицах

    ```bsh
    cp /tmp/foo_site_export/{logs,sales}.* ./foo_site
    chown mysql:mysql foo_site -R
    ```
14. Импортируем данные

    ```sql
    ALTER TABLE logs IMPORT TABLESPACE;
    ALTER TABLE sales IMPORT TABLESPACE;
    ```

Стоит заметить, что пункты 1-9 являются подготовкой данных и их можно выполнять там где нет важных данных, а все последующие пункты можно выполнять уже на целевом сервере.

Answer (score -2):

Ок, по базам: если нужен InnoDB - то:
 1. На источнике сменить тип на MyISAM
 2. Остановить сервер
 3. Скопировать
 4. На приемнике сделать тип InnoDB
 5. На исходнике вернуть InnoDB
 6. Запустить сервер на исходнике

Comment: 1 пункт очень ресурсоёмкий для больших БД, решение неуниверсальное.